# Modal display onclick jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, bootstrap-modal

I want to display modal on button click. I've followed bootstrap documentation, but for some reason the modal isn't popping up.Here is my code:

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="commonModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">

                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>.............</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                ..........
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Button:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-view-details"
data-toggle="modal"> View Details</button>
```

Jquery:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
            $('button.btn-view-details').on('click', function () {
                $('#commonModal').modal('show');
            })
 })
```

Comment: Any console error ?

Comment: no, there wasn't any. The accepted answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your button, you can add `data-target` attribute and you don't need to trigger the popup via jQuery:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-view-details"
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#commonModal"> View Details</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add just bootstrap cdns

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button.btn-view-details').on('click', function() {
    $('#commonModal').modal('show');
  })
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="commonModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">

        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>.............</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        ..........
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
Button:

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-view-details" data-toggle="modal"> View Details</button>
```